# Running .net core docker image, says application started, but on browsing gives "This site can’t be reached" error

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having Windows 10 Home operating system. I have installed Docker toolbox.

My docker file is as follows:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-sdk-projectjson

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

I have created docker image by using following command:

```
$ docker build -t test:webApp3 .
```

I tried running the image by using following commands:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:5000 -t test:webApp3

$ docker run test:webApp3
```

Command says application started, but on browsing gives "**This site can’t be reached**" error.

Can someone please tell me, why its giving me specified error?

Plus can someone tell me, where does docker save created images on Windows 10 OS?

Comment: post `docker ps` to check if your containers are running, `docker logs` of your running containers

Comment: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/107 this might helps you

Comment: how are you opening your site? If you use your docker toolbox then you should use the ip of the virtual machine as in http://192.168.99.100:8080 (assuming that's the ip of your docker VM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by referring to following link:
https://medium.com/trafi-tech-beat/running-net-core-on-docker-c438889eb5a#.s3krizvtw

I was required to add, `.UseUrls("http://*:5000/")` in Main() of Program.cs.

Then I was able to browse, by using following URL:

http://192.168.99.100:5000/api/values